# Get directional vector from point A to point B

Tags: matrices

Im currently trying to figure out following vector maths problem:

I have a point $A$ and a point $B$ and I want to get the directional vector (if that's incorrect, please tell me) that is needed to go from $A$ to $B$. Normally I would get this vector as a user-based input, like something from a gamepad, keyboard, etc. Since this is a mathematical simulation though, I "just" need the exact vector I need to apply on each iteration to move towards the destination $B$ (About one unit per iteration, like $(1, 0, 0.5)$).

I hope I outlined my problem understandable enough, if not just tell me in a comment.

Much thanks in advance!

**Example:**
If $A = (0,0,0)$ and $B = (3, 0, 0)$ the "directional vector" that I'd need would be  $(1, 0, 0)$, since I only need to move along the first axis.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you want. What quantities do you have, and what do you want to calculate from them?

Comment: So you are looking for a unit vector in the direction of the directional vector?

Comment: I added a comment that might help with further clarification. The current values are just picked randomly out of my head, but could be vectors out of a real 3D space. In my system I just want to let an entity (can be a human, a box - its shape doesn't really matter) to move towards my target `B`. Since I don't want it to travel all the way in one go, I wanted it to slowly move towards my goal - maybe over 4 iterations - and thats where I'm currently having my problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector pointing in the direction from point $A$ to point $B$ is $\vec{BA} = \vec{OB} - \vec{OA}$.  In your case you'd have $\vec {AB}=(3,0,0)-(0,0,0) = (3,0,0)$.  Then if you'd like to normalize it, you divide by its length: $\widehat {AB} = \dfrac {(3,0,0)}{3}=(\dfrac 33, \dfrac 03, \dfrac 03)=(1,0,0)$.

In case you've forgotten (or haven't taken linear algebra), the length of a vector $(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n)$ is just $(a_1^2+a_2^2+\cdots +a_n^2)^{1/2}$.

If you'd like a vector $\vec v$ such that $\vec{AB}=4\vec v$ (or however many iterations you want), then after you find $\vec{AB}$, you divide it by that number, that is $\vec v=\dfrac {\vec{AB}}{4}$.

Comment: Thanks for the tip with the normalizing, that did the trick for me. I have taken linear algebra, but its been some time since I last refreshed my memory ;)

Comment: @SpaceEmotion Happy to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are looking for a unit vector in the direction of the direction vector from $A$ to $B$. To get that, you calculate the direction vector, and the divide each coordinate by the length of the vector: $\sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2}$. If you want even smaller iterations, you can divide each coordinate by twice, or ten times the distance between the points.

Comment: Yes, a unit vector is what I searched for. Thanks for the hint!